# Copy a Azure table (SAS) to a db on Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, azure

Just that: Is there a way to copy a azure table (with SAS connection) to a db on Microsoft SQL Server? It could be possible with python?

Thank you all!

I've tried on SSIS visual studio 2019 with no success

Comment: @jarlh - [tag:sas] is almost certainly not relevant here, it refers to a programming langauge, not shared access signatures which is the more common usage of 'SAS' in this context.

Comment: **azure table** - Does it mean azure table storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **azure data factory ** or **azure synapse** to copy the data from azure table storage to azure SQL database. Refer **MS document** on [Introduction to Azure Data Factory - Azure Data Factory | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/introduction) if you are new to data factory.

Refer **MS document** on [Copy data to and from Azure Table storage - Azure Data Factory & Azure Synapse | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-table-storage?tabs=data-factory).

I tried to repro this in my environment.

- Linked services are for Azure table storage and azure sql database.
- In the linked service for azure table storage's Authentication method, SAS URI is selected and URL and token is given.

[image]

- Similarly, linked service for Azure Sql databse is created by giving server name, database name, username and password.

[image]

- Then Copy activity is taken and source dataset for table storage is created and given the same in source settings.

[image]

[image]

- Similarly, sink dataset is created.

[image]

[image]

Once source and sink datasets are configured in copy activity, pipeline is run to copy data from table storage to Azure SQL DB.

By this way, Data can be copied from azure table storage with SAS key to Azure SQL Database.